# Pip does not work on linux returning error:“from urllib3.packages.ordered_dict import OrderedDict ImportError: No module named ordered_dict”

Tags: python, pip, importerror

I noticed i couldn't use pip anymore because of Import error whatever i do with pip, can't eve just run "pip" without getting:

cannot install urllib3 or setuputils using pip so i tryed downloading and then setup.py install them. Nothing worked

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, 
in load_entry_point
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, 
in load_entry_point
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, 
in load
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, 
in resolve
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in 
<module>
from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in 
<module>
from pip.download import path_to_url
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in 
<module>
import requests, six
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 80, in 
<module>
from . import utils
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 25, in 
<module>
from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/compat.py", line 94, in 
<module>
from urllib3.packages.ordered_dict import OrderedDict
ImportError: No module named ordered_dict
```

if i try ti pip install anything it gives me the error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Reinstall pip using your operating system's package handler.

Comment: @snakecharmerb already tried, nothing changed